# Auxiliary variable Gibbs sampler

Tags: bayesian, gibbs, auxiliary-variable

Suppose we want to sample from a pdf $f(x_1,x_2)$. It's easy to sample from $x_1 \vert x_2$, but not $x_2 \vert x_1$, so we introduce an auxiliary variable $u$ such that $\int f(x_1,x_2,u) du = f(x_1,x_2)$, and it's easier to sample $x_2 \vert x_1, u$. Then, given $(x_1^{(t)}, x_2^{(t)}, u^{(t)})$, we do:

1. Sample $x_1^{(t+1)} \sim f(x_1 \vert x_2^{(t)})$
2. Sample $x_2^{(t+1)} \sim f(x_2 \vert x_1^{(t+1)}, u^{(t)})$
3. Sample $u^{(t+1)} \sim f(u \vert x_1^{(t+1)}, x_2^{(t+1)})$

Does this Gibbs sampling procedure give us valid samples from $f(x_1,x_2)$? If so, why is this true?

Comment: Is it in fact the case that $f(x_1|x_2,u) = f(x_1|x_2)$?

Comment: In general, no, they're not the same.

Comment: Then your first sample (for $x_1$) needs to be conditional on $u$ as well as $x_2$.

Comment: I agree that if we use $f(x_1 \vert x_2, u)$ in step 1 the algorithm would definitely produce valid samples from $f(x_1,x_2)$. My question is about whether the samples are still valid if we use $f(x_1 \vert x_2)$ in step 1 instead. Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $(x_1^{(t)}, x_2^{(t)},u^{(t)})$ is distributed from the joint distribution $f(x_1^{(t)}, x_2^{(t)},u^{(t)})$, $(x_1^{(t+1)}, x_2^{(t)},u^{(t)})$ is distributed from$$f(x_1^{(t)} \mid x_2^{(t)}) \times f(x_2^{(t)},u^{(t)})$$which differs from$$f(x_1^{(t)} \mid x_2^{(t)},u^{(t)}) \times f(x_2^{(t)},u^{(t)})$$in general. Hence Step 1 does not keep the target as the stationary distribution in general.